# Deactivate default a:active behaviour on ios

Tags: css, ios, pseudo-class

When clicking on a link in safari with ios, a grey, semi-opaque rectangle appears around the link. Is it possible to deactivate this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You certainly can, the simplest way would be to use the following:

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
        tap-highlight-color: transparent;
```

You can also change it to whatever colour you would like. Keep in mind that indicating that a link has been pressed is helpful to the user.

Comment: Great! I know that but it was for a kind of roundabout way to use link. Thx